# Find $\mathbf a$ for which the following equation has triple roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find $\mathbf a \in\mathbb{R}$ for which the following equation has triple roots:

$$ x^4-5x^3+\mathbf ax^2-7x+2=0$$

Comment: If your polynomial $p(x)$ has a triple root at some $x=r$, then $p(x) = (x-r)^3 (x-R)$ for some other real root $R$. Then, $p''(x)$ also has a root at $r$. Then
$$
p''(x) = 12x^2-30x+2a
$$
so you can pick the two roots and reconstruct the original polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r_1$ be the triple root.  Then there must be an additional single root $r_2$ to match the fourth degree equation.

Then from the Vieta formulas:

$3r_1+r_2=5$

$r_1^3r_2=2$

Eliminating $r_2$ from this pair:

$r_1^3(5-3r_1)=2$

$3r_1^4-5r_1^3+2=0$

This has multiple roots because there are different choices for the triple root.  Here we shall take the obvious rational root $r_1=1$, whereupon $r_2=2$.

Then the polynomial must factor as $(x-1)^3(x-2)$ and $a$ is determined accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A triple root of $f$ is also a root of $f''$, and so is a root of their [resultant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5Bx%5E4+-+5+x%5E3+%2B+a+x%5E2+-+7+x+%2B+2,+12x%5E2-30x%2B2a,x%5D), which is $$400 a^4 - 2400 a^3 - 82080 a^2 + 892944 a - 2262816$$

It so happens that $a=9$ is a root (and the only nice one), but let's avoid guessing.

A triple root of $f$ is also a root of $f'$, and so is a root of their [resultant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Resultant%5Bx%5E4+-+5+x%5E3+%2B+a+x%5E2+-+7+x+%2B+2,+D%5Bx%5E4+-+5+x%5E3+%2B+a+x%5E2+-+7+x+%2B+2,x%5D,x%5D), which is $$32 a^4 - 396 a^3 - 4887 a^2 + 90882 a - 343359
$$
Now, the gcd of these two polynomials in $a$ is $a-9$ and so only $a=9$ works.

Comment: That is the correct answer.Thanks!

Comment: Also a root of the first derivative, maybe?

Comment: @OscarLanzi, you're quite right. Thanks for the push.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $b$ is the triple root. Then the polynomial can be factored as $(x-b)^3(x-c)$ and we get
$$
x^4 - (3b+c)x^3 + (3b^2 + 3bc)x^2 - (b^3+3b^2c)x + b^3c
$$
so we need
\begin{cases}
3b+c=5 \\
3b^2+3bc=a\\
b^3+3b^2c=7\\
b^3c=2
\end{cases}
Multiplying the third equation by $b$ and taking into account the fourth equation we get
$$
b^4-7b+6=0
$$
The fourth equation, together with the first, becomes $5b^3-3b^4=2$
$$
3b^4-5b^3+2=0
$$
Obviously $b=1$ is a solution for both. If $b\ne1$ we get
\begin{cases}
b^3+b^2+b-6=0 \\
3b^3-2b^2-2b-2=0
\end{cases}
and, eliminating $b^3$,
$$
5b^2+5b-16=0
$$
Multiplying the top equation by $2$ and summing up,
$$
5b^3-14=0
$$
Since $5b^3+5b^2-16b=0$, we get $5b^2-16b+14=0$, that finally yields $5b-16=-16b+14$, or $b=10/7$, that doesn't satisfy $5b^3=14$.

Therefore $b=1$ and $c=2$, so $a=9$.